# Using CIFS crendentials file with OpenELEC

Tags: openelec

I've recently converted from using Raspbmc to OpenELEC on my Raspberry Pi. I was attempting to map a network share but its a little different as the majority of the filesystem on OpenELEC is made as read only, meaning you can't use fstab.

The wiki article details how to mount a CIFS share with systemd instead:

http://wiki.openelec.tv/index.php?title=Mounting_network_shares

On the options part I tried using the credentials parameter but it doesn't seem to work. Likewise I can't run it manually when using the mount command.

1. Is it possible to specify a credentials file in this way when not using fstab?
2. Would it be beneficial as the /storage directory is protected by SSH Private/Public Key Auth